# Changed behaviour regarding web3.eth.accounts[0] in Metamask?

Tags: metamask

Some time ago, it was possible to get the selected account using sync methods on web3 0.2.
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md

It always worked on our DAPP. But on Nov 8th in the middle  of afternoon it changed. I was testing my dapp locally (9545) and I noticed that I could not retrieve my accounts anymore. I was using a version of Metamask download before Nov 2th when the error happened.

I noticed that it was still possible to retrieve accounts when using the asyncronous methods. But sync is not working anymore. Is it the case? Does anyone knows why it happened? Is it related to that Metamask change of Nov 2th?

I was using web3-injected from metamask.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

6th of November MetaMask stopped injecting web3, introduced Private Mode with some breaking changes. You can take a look https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, Aquila. I was aware of that. But, I did not updated my metamask when the error happened. So, how this happen? Do you think the injected web3 lib is dinamically feched by Metamask and then injected?

Comment: metamask still injects web3 under 'window.web3', changes only apply if you turn privacy mode on.

Comment: Yes, Roberto. This is also true. But something happen because this DAPP was working for more than 6 months and it happened 2 days after this breaking change.

Comment: @SuzanaMaranhão The plugin already had been modified in a previous update but the new feature will activate only after november 8.

Comment: @Ismael, where did you read about this new feature activation on Nov 8th? My error was on Nov 8th, so it can explain eveything. I solved the problem already. I am just trying to understand what happened.

Comment: @SuzanaMaranhão It is a common pattern, ie ethereum clients are updated well in advance to a fork.